# SharePoint Conditional Formatting without using Designer

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, conditional

I am trying to apply conditional formatting to my SharePoint list based on a few conditions.

For example I have a column (Month Needed) that the user selects a date from a drop down list in the format 11/2015 and so on. I would like to highlight (with colors) any row that has a date that is 90 days or less from the current date?

Unfortunately my **SharePoint** site does not allow me to create web parts in Designer so I am unable to add conditions that way and the JavaScript examples I have found don't really do what I need it to.

Here is an example of what I found: 
http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2008/11/sharepoint-color-coding-sharepoint.html

so a statement like the following:

```
if(text in Month Needed Column is 90 days less than Current date)
{
        background color = 'red';
}
```

Any guidance on how to accomplish this would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Tag your sharepoint version. Do you have permission to edit page and add script/content editor webpart?

Comment: @AmalHashim, yes I do have access to add script and use the CEWP.

Comment: This question has two applicable answers (including one of my own!) http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119277/client-side-rendering-js-link-status-changes-in-sharepoint-list/119336#119336

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2013 we can use JSLinks to enhance how list views are displayed.

1. Create a js file and store it in any of the library (SiteAssets)
2. Inside the js file you can handle `ItemOverride` to add your specific condition and color change logic.

Detailed explanation can be found http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/04/color-code-list-items-with-javascript-using-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013/

http://yalla.itgroove.net/2014/09/25/conditional-color-coding-sharepoint-2013-task-list-using-jslink/