# Dynamic Calculated column in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, out-of-the-box

I have a calculated column that calculates today date dynamically

I followed this [link](https://sharepoint2020.wordpress.com/2015/05/17/display-todays-date-in-a-calculated-column-with-javascript/#comment-715)

problem is calculated column in number data type. I want it as Date and Time date format.

I want to calculate date difference between dynamic today date and another Overdue date field.

Can you help me please...

Comment: You can try as mentioned in this link: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171222/count-not-updating-in-calculated-column/171482#171482

Answer (score 2):

**First,** you should be aware of the output of the two date difference should be in `Days` or `Months` or `Years` as a **Number**!

If you set `The data type returned from this formula` as DateTime, it would work but it logically would **show invalid data**.

[image]

So the difference should be shown as Number **Not** as Date format!

---

To get the diff between today and overdue date through this calculated column formula

```
=DATEDIF([overdue date],TODAY(),"d")
```

[image]

> **Note:**
>
> The calculated column formula is only calculated/updated in the
>   following cases:
>
> - Add New Item.
> - Update Existing item.
> - Update the calculated column itself in the List Setting!

**Check Also**

- [The supported and unsupported columns in SharePoint calculated column formula](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)

---

**To update the calculated column daily**

Try to Create a **Retention Policy** to run a workflow which updates the list items daily!!

- Check the detail steps at [Automatically update a column with a type of calculated value in a SharePoint List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKWNM.png)

Or instead of using calculated column, use JSlink as mentioned at [Days Past Since List Item Created - SharePoint Online 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113313/days-past-since-list-item-created-sharepoint-online-2013)

Comment: TODAY() function will calculate dynamically or static function..

Comment: =IF (ISERROR(DATEDIF(TODAY(),[Renewal Date 01],"d")),"DUE",DATEDIF(TODAY(),[Renewal Date 01],"d"))

Comment: If it is dynamic ok for me otherwise have to update daily...

Comment: bro, please read my answer carefully, I mentioned The calculated column formula is only calculated/updated in the following cases:

- Add New Item.- Update Existing item.-Update the calculated column itself in the List Setting! so today will get the current date when the above-mentioned actions happened ! also I have updated my answer with workarounds to calculate it dynamically !!

Comment: Ok got it. I understood

Comment: It isn't dynamic if you need to update it manually.